# Django complex relationship

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

I've the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

I now want a model C which has a field that has multiple unique combinations of A and B like in ManyToMany field. I found that for mapping ForeignKey to two models GenericForeignKey can be used. I've tried GenericForeignKey like below:

```
class C(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    property1 = models.CharField()
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    a_b = GenericForeignKey(store, category)
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm new to Django as well as SQL.

Edit: Clarified the requirement of combinations.

Edit2: Current working model:

I've created below models as a working solution:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    property1 = models.CharField()

class A_B_C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

It is this model that I was avoiding to create explicitly and maintain within relations. I would like to know if this solution would be efficient or is there another Django way to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

I've created below models as a working solution:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    property1 = models.CharField()

class A_B_C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `ManyToManyField` Django creates intermediate table for you implicitly. In your example you'll get additional table with columns `(id, a_id, b_id)`. But you can define it explicitly and set a `through` option on a field `a` on `B` model, and then define `unique_together` for this intermediate model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='C')

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("a", "b")
```

Note: If I remember correctly, you can't set unique_together on `ManyToManyFiled` directly.

Comment: Well this worked, but I need multiple combinations of a, b to be possible, too, like in ManyToMany type relations. Will that be possible here?

Comment: This is an explicit Many-To-Many, but since you wrote _"I now want a model C which has a field that is unique combination of A and B."_ it adds a unique constraint.

Comment: With code written above, suppose aN is instance of A and bN is instance of B, you can have i.e.: (a1-b1, a2-b1, a3-b1, a1-b2, a2-b2, a2-b3, a3-b1, a3-b2, a3-b3) relations, this of course allows reverse lookup (thank to Django ORM), i.e. (b1-a1, b1-a2, b1-a3, etc.). But due to unique_together, you can't have (a1-b1, **a1-b2**, a2-b1, a2-b2, **a1-b2**).

Comment: As per your last comment, I need that a1-b1, a1-b2 can be mapped to c1. Right now, c1 can have either a1-b1 or a1-b2. I've refined the question to include this comment.

Comment: Well, this is one of the solutions, that you included in your edit in the question. Though since your C model is quite simple, the other way is to includefields from C directly to A_B_C, this is a denormalization of data model, it will save you a 'join' when quering but will take more storage space, so before doing this it's best to benchmark if you really need it.

Comment: Also, when things get more complicated it's not that bad if it's done more explicitly. Sometimes relying on some implicit magic is not good.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your views!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a job for GenericForeignKey. Instead you need to define the `unique_together` Meta attribute:

```
class C(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta
        unique_together = ('a', 'b')
```

Comment: I gave this a try and ManyToManyField isn't allowed here.

Comment: Trying to understand what you actually need here. A and B are already linked via a M2M, why do you need two extra M2Ms? Could you be looking for a [custom through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) on that relationship, maybe?